# Condition in style attribute is not evaluated on postback

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

I am trying to implement the following requirement:

1. Show error message in tooltip for validation error
2. Highlight the component whose validation fails.

I've implemented as follows.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <a4j:outputPanel id="studentPanel"> 
             <h:inputText value="#{studentBean.studentNumber}" id="studentNumber" style="#{not component.valid ? 'border-color:red;' : 'border-color:none;'}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg.studentNoValidationMsg}">
             </h:inputText>
             <rich:tooltip for="studentNumber"> 
                 <rich:message for="studentNumber"></rich:message>
             </rich:tooltip>
          </a4j:outputPanel>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If validation fails, tooltip appears with validation message. However, the component is not highlighted in red. Am I missing any step?

Comment: Are you managing the component rendering yourself or do you submit the complete form?

Comment: I am submitting the complete form.

Comment: Are you using `form` or `h:form`